# Hyper-V VM Internet connection not working

Tags: networking, server, connection, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I am working at a company and have been tasked with setting up a server with a VM for clients. I have hit a wall with this problem, and I have no experience with this at all so I am posting here to ask for help.

The problem is that the internet connection is not working on the VM. The connection is limited and I cannot access the internet at all. I have been following a few guides I found for setting up the VM so far so I have set up the virtual switch and everything, I dont know why its not working. I think some of my configuration of the VM or the virtual switch are wrong, but so far with hours of googling I have not found any configurations that have fixed the problem.

I have made an album that shows all the configurations that relate to this issue(I think, if I need to show something else please let me know). [Here it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJ2TC.jpg).

- There is the properties of the connections on the server
- The virtual switch manager
- The settings of the VM
- The diagnostic of the connection on the VM

I have messed with the IP & DNS settings of the adapter on the VM for hours but nothing has worked or changed the error, the configuration now is reset back to the default for the album.

I think this is a longshot, but I am really stuck here and I need to fix this problem. If anyone knows why I have this problem, or has any useful info or tips please let me know, thanks!

Oh and also if this is not the appropriate place for this type of post please let me know the right place to go asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So just posting this in case anyone in the future reads this post or has the same problem, the solution was obtaining a fail over IP.